# failing to install mongoose npm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I am installing mongoose as an npm.  I am getting back a bunch of errors. I did a npm install of **npm install -g node-gyp**  from a post I read about with a similar problem.  However, my problem did not seem to go away.  I am not able to problem solve the warning on this one.  Any insight would be hugely appreciated.

```
   ../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/kerberos.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/stevenkauyedauty/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/stevenkauyedauty/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/stevenkauyedauty/projects/controllerAs/beerRecipes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Are you running Mac? Are you using XCode 6?

Comment: `xcodebuild -version`

Comment: Ok. I just saw your comment below I am on 6.4.  I will upgrade

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: Apparently.  I am now using mongoose.

Comment: Awesome glad it worked! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining about the library `lgcc_s.10.5` not existing on your system. You can see a similar issue with Homebrew [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653). If you are on Mac, then the proposed solution is to upgrade to XCode 7.

Figure out your XCode version:

```
vinay@chocobo-2:~ $ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.0.1
```

Comment: If this does not work for you, then I will work with you to update my answer and get you up and running.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 7.1 ... It's still throwing the same error. On OSX. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the same exact error? Please ask a new question and ping me if it's the same error and you have Xcode 7.1 installed and link this question.

Comment: Correction, I am getting the same warning (first line of the snippet in OP's question). ```../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning``` and yes I have Xcode 7.1 installed.

Comment: Please create a new question and link me. I will help you.

Comment: @Vinay Any solution to this? I'm in the same situation. I'm on Xcode 7.1.

Comment: @Richard is it the exact same error? That it cannot find libgcc? If that's the case, please open a new question, reference this one and post the link here. It will be difficult for me to help you out in the comments section here if your issue is different but results in the same error.

Comment: @Vinay Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636605/npm-install-mongoose-kerberos-error-gss-acquire-cred-impersonate-name. Thanks!