# How to install Mongoose with NPM without warnings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I continually get this error:

```
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
```

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140089/failing-to-install-mongoose-npm/33140170#33140170